# Vb.net combobox formatstring property doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, forms, combobox, format, currency

I have a form created in VB.net. It is used to get some information form a user. The form is not bound to any data source.

A combobox on this form is used to enter a cost. I want the value entered by the user to be displayed using currency format. I have used the Format String Dialog that opens from the ellipses button on the FormatString property of the combobox and selected Currency. This put C2 into the FormatString property.

When I run my application, this format is not applied to the value entered into the combobox at the time the number is entered or when I leave the combobox.

What am I missing?

Comment: That property only works for bound controls.

Answer (score 0):

Set the FormattingEnabled Property to True.

Comment: Sorry - I should have said that FormattingEnabled is also set to True.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormatString` property works only for data-bound controls. However, the input in a control can still be formatted with the `ToString()` method on a `Change` or `Leave` event.

The code sample below will format the text in the combo box to the default currency once the focus leaves control. Error handling can be done in the `else` clause:

```
private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = comboBox1.Text;
    decimal result;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(s, out result))
    {
        comboBox1.Text = result.ToString("C2");
    }
}
```